# removing underscore form a string

Tags: java

I have a string that looks like this

```
abcd= "name_person"
```

but I would like it to read like this:

```
abcd= "nameperson"
```

how can I do this with Java.

Comment: its good to downvote a question, but people should try to add comment on why you actually down voted the question.. This would help new users using this website to formulate the question more clearly and show that they have put effort before asking here

Comment: @Barry it would also help the stigma of this site being noob/learner/student unfriendly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
abcd = abcd.replaceAll("_", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
  abcd = abcd.replaceAll("_", "");
```

This will replace all occurrences of underscore with nothing, so you are left without underscores.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string replace function:

```
abcd.replace("_", "");
```

Comment: replace() is only for the first instance of the sequence in the string

Comment: @La-comadreja technically it works for the example given